# React native full screen intent notification

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I have an app that needs to show a **full screen notification** even when the phone is locked or the app is closed, something like ubber, when the user orders a driver i want the driver to be able to see a fullscreen notification that shows the details of the order and some action buttons that might reject the order, accept it, or open some activity in the app like checking the users profile or something.

I don't want it to be just a normal notification because the whole buisness kinda depends on it, the driver needs to be instantly informed about the order and react to it, that can be best achived with implementing a full screen notification just like answering a call, it's a time-sensitive message.

Is this possible with react native and some push notification service like OneSignal?

After doing some research i found that this may be achievable with Android using services and full screen notification intent, but in ios it's more complicated since background tasks are very restricted in iOS.

So im just looking for some insight on how to achieve this or at least something similar, is it even possible to achieve something like this? Do i have to write some platform specific code for both iOS and Android?

ANY help at all is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I this this link will help you https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1482